How to stop PyCharm from displaying all columns of a table?
I use Python notebooks in PyCharm. I work with tables which typically have a few thousand of columns and a few thousand of rows. Sometimes I want to get a quick overview of the table / DataFrame. I am used to typing nameofmynumpyarray in a cell and execute it, from when I was using Jupyter Notebooks in the browser.
The issue with doing this in PyCharm is that it always freezes for a while while trying to load the entire table and display it. I don't need it do display the entire table. I just want a quick overview. The number of rows is not the problem, because by default it only shows 10 rows and I can go through them 10 by 10. But it always shows the full number of rows and therefore PyCharm freezes any time I execute a cell which should display a table with high number of columns.
Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

your issue is short on details ... so this is an assumption (as you mention dataframe !) , if it a pandas dataframe , try something along the following :  pd.options.display.max_rows =  25
pd.options.display.max_columns = 15  ..... , or give more details
